# Url rewriting workbut not on the link inside the application

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2.4

Do you have anyidea about this problem, I have this URL,

```
http://localhost/boutique/index.php/Products/Description/products_id,2
```

I rewrite via `.htaccess` to have this

```
http://localhost/boutique/Products/Description/products_id,2

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

When I click on product link I have this

```
http://localhost/boutique/Products/Description/products_id,2
```

but inside the application the link is always like this :

```
http://localhost/boutique/index.php/Products/Description/products_id,2
```

I haven't found the solution. If you have an idea or if you've experienced the same problem, I am interested.

Comment: This suggests that you have a total miss conception of how rewriting works. Rewriting rules operate on _incoming_ requests. They do _not_ magically change links send out, so by some application or whatever.

Comment: "I rewrite via htaccess to have this" - that directive isn't a "rewrite", it's an external redirect that _removes_ the `index.php` part of the URL. You must have a rewrite elsewhere in your config file that routes the request? "but inside the application the link is..." - the problem may be inside your application. You shouldn't _need_ the first redirect that removes the `index.php` part. Are you linking to pages using the `index.php` part?